# html list li width and height

Tags: html, css, list, height, width

This is my page:
http://www.clouderize.it/michele/
As you can see the menu voice "Storia del Bernese" is upper than the other li voice.
I want that all the li has the same height but different width, based on text lenght.

What change I have to do in my css?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Solving your issue but by changing the HTML rather dramatically (hence not an answer) is this http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/2XDgV/. Breaking all the "rules" and using `<a>` only (rather than `<li>`) allows you to use `display: inline-block;` without compatibility worries (any default `inline` element can be turned into `inline-block` even in old browsers). Then apply all your styles to the links directly, flexible widths and all. Could just as easily be fixed widths as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi now define to your `li white-space nowrap`

as like this

```
    #menu-Principale li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: to complete Rohit's answer, do not use image with fixed width as background. You can split your button in three parts for the background (left side, center, right side) with a repeat-x on the center item (1px*36px img) to render your button or you can also do your gradient with CSS3

Comment: but I haven't an id called menu-principale....where I have to add this css property?

Comment: @michele here is id http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDJn8.png check  now add this css in your file anywhere

Comment: http://gradients.glrzad.com/ you can create gradients using this website (one of many providing this kind of service) just apply the style to your `li` it should be fine

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` you can feel that it's working, but it is not the right way when you give the `container` a fixed width. because the contents will go outside the cell. you should consider other or old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you used:
ul, menu, dir {
display: block;

...
}

You would be better off using display:inline; and not setting the width (or set to auto for browser compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

in your code a tag has below css

```
  a.tabInactive {
    background: url("images/menu_normal.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        display: block;
        line-height: 33px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 76px;
    }
```

`menu_normal.png` size is `77 X 34` which is small for your menu `Storia del Bernese`

So you have to create one more image with size that fit to your menu.
then create new class for id `li10` it will work

Answer (score -1):

Do not fix the width to li. Need not to mention the height also, as we are giveng top padding Give it like this

```
#menu-Principale li{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:6px 4px;
 width:auto
}
```

Comment: did you understand my answer and didn't fix the problem or you just down-voted it for no reason?

Answer (score -1):

Remove tab width, add padding to the right and left, fix background image. 
Now you just need to fine-tune the background image/color.

```
a.tabInactive {
    display: block;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: auto;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

a.tabInactive:hover {
    display:block;
    line-height:33px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: auto;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #CCC;
}

a.tabActive {
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    line-height: 33px;
    width: auto;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #7F469D;
}
```